what can cause this error? Illuminate\Database\QueryException
I am trying to work on an existing laravel project when I clone and run php artisan migrate I get this error
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = x_min and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760
     // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the erro         
    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception         
   // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.

    759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
    761▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    762▕             );
    763▕         }
    764▕     }
 

This is my settings for mysql in config/database.php file
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'x_min'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

And my .env file
APP_ENV="local"

APP_TIMEZONE="Asia/Dhaka"

APP_NAME="QRPAY"

APP_KEY=base64:ZWYVDObkNN+ScglQBDGprdv5z2cplCDPcuBsB+PSUdo=

APP_DEBUG="true"

APP_URL="http://localhost:8000"

APP_MODE="debug"

LOG_CHANNEL="stack"

LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL="null"

LOG_LEVEL="debug"

DB_CONNECTION="mysql"

DB_HOST="127.0.0.1"
# DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT="3306"

DB_DATABASE="x_min"

DB_USERNAME="root"

DB_PASSWORD=""

BROADCAST_DRIVER="pusher"

CACHE_DRIVER="file"

FILESYSTEM_DISK="local"

QUEUE_CONNECTION="database"

SESSION_DRIVER="file"

SESSION_LIFETIME="120"

MEMCACHED_HOST="127.0.0.1"

REDIS_HOST="127.0.0.1"

REDIS_PASSWORD="null"

REDIS_PORT="6379"

MAIL_MAILER="smtp"

MAIL_HOST=""

MAIL_PORT="465"

MAIL_USERNAME=""

MAIL_PASSWORD=""

MAIL_ENCRYPTION="ssl"

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=""

MAIL_FROM_NAME="QRPAY"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=""

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=""

AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"

AWS_BUCKET=""

AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT="false"

PUSHER_APP_ID="1574360"

PUSHER_APP_KEY="971ccaa6176db78407bf"

PUSHER_APP_SECRET="a30a6f1a61b97eb8225a"

PUSHER_HOST=""

PUSHER_PORT="443"

PUSHER_SCHEME="https"

PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="ap2"

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY=""

VITE_PUSHER_HOST=""

VITE_PUSHER_PORT="443"

VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="https"

VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="mt1"

SHELL_VERBOSITY="0"


The database is really large
I have ran composer install, restarted the server, the database exists very well I called it x_min. I have used meta AI and tried the suggestions but nothing is working

Try uppercase INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

@Barmar I don't think this is a manually generated query where the OP can simply rewrite the SQL statement. This looks like the migration checking for the existence of a table.

Sounds like maybe the database is configured with case sensitivity, and the migration tool expects it to be insensitive.

@Barmar mysql error 2002 is a connection error, it indicates that the socket file could not be found. The SQL statement in this case is a red herring.

You have posted your Pusher credentials here, you should change those now they are public.
